# How to scrape prices from a HTML paragraph based on preceding text with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to scrape prices from a paragraph and store them in a database with Nokogiri. The paragraph looks like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
   Sed elit nisi, tincidunt id purus vitae, imperdiet 
   vulputate diam 50.00, imperdiet vulputate diam 100.00 ...</p>
```

The text is always the same in each paragraph, the numbers are the only thing that change. I know how to select the entire paragraph with css selectors using Nokogiri, but is there a way to select each price from the paragraph based on the preceding text? Something like

```
value1 = doc.?('vulputate diam ')
```

would give a value of '50.00' to value1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Regex match on your paragraph result. `.match(/vulputate diam ([\d\.]+)/)`

```
x = "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed elit nisi, tincidunt id purus vitae, imperdiet vulputate diam 50.00, imperdiet vulputate diam 100.00 ...</p>".match(/vulputate diam ([\d\.]+)/)
x.captures
# => ["50.00"]
```

Also the same use with `scan` as Philip Hallstrom suggested is great.

Comment: Or `str.scan(/vulputate diam ([\d.]+)/)` which returns `[["50.00"], ["100.00"]]`